# Cannot connect to database when using external IP addres of machine

Tags: mariadb, database-connection

I am using MariaDB 10.2.22 and cannot connect to database using external IP address of machine, but only when doing it from this very machine.

There is no skip-networking and address binding is not restricted. Grants for '%' and for 'localhost' has been created, `FLUSH PRIVILEGES` and even server restart has been done.

When connecting using 'localhost' with credentials there is no problem. When connecting using ip (of external interface) as hostname there is no problem as long as I am connecting from other machine on Internet.

When I am using the same IP address (from external interface) and same credentials, but doing connection from machine the server is hosted on - there is sad message:

```
mysql:host=11.22.33.44;dbname=myDatabase
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'dbUser'@'Hostname.of.Machine' (using password: YES)
```

Anyone has any guesses what is causing such behavior?

Comment: Were you `GRANTed` access from that IP?  Or just from localhost?

Comment: @RickJames: localhost and '%'. I thought that '%' will do for everything else than localhost.